Computing the third covariant derivative
I want to prove the following formula given in Petersen (3rd Edition).
\begin{align}
    \nabla^3_{X,Y,Z}W &= \nabla^2_{X,Y } (\nabla_Z W) - \nabla_{\nabla^2_{X,Y}Z}W\\
    \nabla^3_{X,Y,Z}W &= \nabla_X (\nabla^2)_{Y,Z} W + \nabla^2_{Y,Z} (\nabla_X W)\\
\end{align}
The hint given to prove this is


these follow from the various ways one can iterate covariant derivatives (and see the following formulas)
$$ \nabla^2_{X,Y} W = \nabla_X (\nabla_Y W) - \nabla_{\nabla_X Y} W  $$
$$ \nabla^2_{X,Y} W = ( \nabla_X \nabla )_Y W + \nabla_Y (\nabla_X W) $$


Here's my attempt:
The two ways to iterate the covariant derivatives would be
$$ \nabla^3W = \nabla^2(\nabla W) = \nabla (\nabla^2 W) $$
For simplicity, write $ S = \nabla W $ and $T = \nabla^2 W $, so that $T=\nabla S$.
Then
\begin{align}
    \nabla^3 W (X,Y,Z) &= \nabla T (X,Y,Z) = \nabla _X T (Y,Z) \\
        &=\nabla_X (T(Y,Z)) - T(\nabla_X Y ,Z) - T(Y, \nabla_X Z) \\
        &=\nabla_X (\nabla S(Y,Z)) - \nabla S(\nabla_X Y ,Z) - \nabla S(Y, \nabla_X Z) \\
        &=\nabla_X \{\nabla_Y (S(Z)) - S(\nabla_Y Z)\} - (\nabla_{\nabla_X Y}S) Z - (\nabla_Y S)(\nabla_X Z) \\
        &=\nabla_X \{\nabla_Y (\nabla_Z W)\} - \nabla_X \{S(\nabla_Y Z)\} - \{ \nabla_{\nabla_X Y}(S(Z)) -S (\nabla_{\nabla_X Y} Z) \} - (\nabla_Y S)(\nabla_X Z) \\
\end{align}
The first and the third term can be combined after noting that $S(Z)=\nabla_Z W$. Further we will elaborate the second term and combine it with the fourth term.
\begin{align}
    \nabla^3 W (X,Y,Z) &= \nabla^2_{X,Y} (\nabla_Z W) - \{ (\nabla_X S)(\nabla_Y Z) + S (\nabla_X(\nabla_Y Z)) \} + S (\nabla_{\nabla_X Y} Z) - (\nabla_Y S)(\nabla_X Z) \\
        &= \nabla^2_{X,Y} (\nabla_Z W)- S (\nabla^2_{X,Y} Z)  + (\nabla_X S)(\nabla_Y Z) - (\nabla_Y S)(\nabla_X Z) \\
\end{align}
The last two terms here are extra. Either they sum to zero or I have made a mistake somewhere in the calculation.
I don't know how to proceed from here.
This question has been asked before here.
But the answers there are not a direct answer to the question I have, nor are the answers complete. The top answer states


Now skew-symmetrization and the Ricci identity should give you what you want.


But those are the steps to prove Bianchi's second identity and not the above relations.
The second answer explains $\nabla^3$ but not the computation.

Can you give the book title?

@TedBlack Riemannian Geometry ~Peter Petersen.

In $ \nabla^2_{X,Y} W = \nabla_X (\nabla_Y W) - \nabla_{\nabla_X Y} W  $ what does $\nabla_{\nabla_X Y}$ denote ? This formula looks superficially like the definition of the covariant derivative.

@TedBlack $ \nabla_X Y = Z $ is a vector field. Then $ \nabla _{\nabla_X Y} W = \nabla_Z W $
